Cover scratches on inside of a car
I would to make these scratches less visible.
How can I do that?


As an experiment, you could try some T-Cut on a small unobstrustive area. Never tried it on plastic though.

The plastic looks matte, rather than shiny. For that, rub damaged areas with a matching grade of adhesive.
In a hidden spot, try varying grades of sandpaper, or non-woven abrasive pads (e.g., ScotchBrite). Also try different strokes to see what best matches the current finish.
N.B.: Hopefully, the color extends through the thickness of the plastic. Test a hidden spot to be sure you won't abrade through a thin surface coat.

Can you show us a plastic surface made beautiful with sandpaper? I am curious to see it. And 3D-printed objects do not count, because they start with an extremely damaged surface (which is natural for 3D-printing) and they just reduce the destruction - which is not the case of this answer.

I read on several sites about this kind of thing, but I did not try it myself.
You use either an electric heat gun, or some open-flame device, to create hot air. The flame must be spread, not concentrated - as needed for cutting.
You "brush" the damaged area with the hot air until the micro-fragments of damage melt back into the volume of the material. While it will not be 100% perfect, it will look much better.
If you use abrasive stuff, you will just replace one damage with different similar damage.
If you use solvents, they have a chance of moving the material down under the force of gravity - and that area will look like melted. That might happen especially if the solvent is strong and used in a bigger quantity.

Heat will damage matte plastic, making it shiny. For matte surfaces, as in the photo, abrasive is the answer.

@DrMoishePippik: I saw the video in the internet some time ago, with this technique applied on matte surface. The idea is to apply just enough heat to melt the "destruction", and insufficient heat to make the matte surface shiny.
